# Как присвоить переменной значение полученное из регулярного выражения в конфиг файле nginx?

Tags: nginx

В конфиг файле сайта на nginx существует регулярное выражение типа:

`subs_filter '<div id="footer">(.*?)<\/div>' '<div id="footer">FOOTER</div>' ir;`

Данная регулярка отрабатывает без проблем. Но возникла необходимость получения контента, которое мы получаем из `(.*?)`.

То есть как получить к примеру то, что находится между `<div id="footer">` и `</div>` и присвоить это к примеру переменной `$need` для дальнейшей замены?

Данное действие необходимо для дальнейшей замены найденного контента в теле всего html кода на другое значение.

В пример привожу аналогичное решение на php:

```
$content='Hello world! <div id="footer">Happy new year!!!</div> Now!';
$matches=null;
preg_match('/<div id="footer">(.*?)<\/div>/is',$content, $matches);
$need=$matches[1];
```

Соответственное мне нужна такая же переменная `$need` но на `nginx`. Какие есть варианты извлечь данное значение для переменной?

Comment: `subs_filter st(\d*).example.com $1.example.com ir;` не подходит? https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/substitutions/

Comment: Не подходит, поскольку данную переменную я могу использовать лишь в моментально поиске/замене, но далее полученное значение я не могу использовать для замены.

Comment: @total-pusher, я добавил код на php для прояснения задачи

Comment: Возможность есть: `if ($uri ~ /by-([^-]+)/) { set $by $1; }` [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5859926/9435985). Только вот переменной с ответом сервера нет. Думаю, вы не сможете провернуть то, что хотите нативными средствами Nginx, этот веб сервер **не предназначен для программирования**. Но есть модуль [lua](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#readme), может с его помощью что и получится.